# How to do cross-site OIDC OAuth without 3rd party cookies?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

Our company owns products on multiple domains, and my team owns the central auth layer for all of them.

Our current approach relies on an OIDC implementation where we store our refresh token as a cookie on the auth service domain, and all the other sites call that domain to maintain their session.

For security purposes, we are not giving our web clients access to the refresh token but rather we store them as HTTP ONLY (so they can't be stolen by 3rd party scripts, XSS and so forth).

All 3 major browsers either implemented or indicated an intent to implement restrictions on 3rd party cookies, which will prevent us from storing the tokens as cookies.

How are we supposed to provide a central OAuth service across domains? I can't find guidance for this, even though I'm sure one should exist (for eg - how is Google doing it for features such as OneTap?)

Anyone has any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a centralized Login, which is a method of authentication orchestrated by a centralized authentication provider for your apps.

- When a user needs authentication, they are redirected to a centralized login page hosted by the authentication provider.
- Post authentication, they are redirected back to the original domain with an authorization code.
- This code is exchanged server-side for access and refresh tokens, which are used to manage the user's session.

Take a look here for more info:
https://dzone.com/articles/authentication-provider-best-practices-centralized

Comment: how does this solve client side refresh though? I want my web clients to be able to refresh their tokens agains the centralized authentication provider

Comment: A user-visible redirection to the centralized login and back would work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a backend for frontend approach to cookie issuing. This will ensure that cookies remain first party and not subject to cookie restrictions introduced in [RFC6265bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis).

So for a web domain of `www.product.com`, either issue cookies from that domain or one that evaluates to having the `same site for cookies`, such as `api.product.com`.

One option for doing so is to use the **token handler pattern**, which deploys utility API endpoints to manage cookies. This avoids impacting JavaScript frontend developers with cookie concerns. My [code example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) shows the developer experience.